# How do I do a multiple loop in a 2D array, multiple matrix

Tags: matrix

How do I do the following search into different matrices each month?
I have 12 to 25 matrices each month

Matrix
nr.      Dd/mm/yyyy    Where           no1 no2 no3 no4 no5
1   23/11/2022  Apple       13  50  74  21  26
1   23/11/2022  Peach           66  22  88  71  77
1   23/11/2022  Blueberry   42  24  20  18  11
1   23/11/2022  Strawberry  13  55  56  65  41
1   23/11/2022  Pear            60  31  25  89  39
1   23/11/2022  Plum            53  54  10  27  5
1   23/11/2022  Apricot     66  22  88  71  77
1   23/11/2022  Mellon          42  24  20  18  11

Matrix
nr.      Dd/mm/yyyy    Where           no1 no2 no3 no4 no5

2   28/11/2022  Apple           63  54  15  31  77
2   28/11/2022  Peach           16  84  37  43  69
2   28/11/2022  Blueberry   78  9   63  86  15
2   28/11/2022  Strawberry  75  78  56  30  82
2   28/11/2022  Pear            22  67  33  13  11
2   28/11/2022  Plum            48  87  2   82  85
2   28/11/2022  Apricot         39  63  34  21  37
2   28/11/2022  Mellon          79  78  38  28  30

All my numbers will be within the range of numbers from 1-90.

I want to search if the sum of  Apple no1 and Apple no2 is found as value in the matrix number 2, 3 , 4 until the last matrix of the month
(case when the sum of the two elements is higher then 90 then it should do  Sum of the 2 elements -90)
For example it is found In Apple, Blueberry and Apricot of matrix2 but it can go further to matrix3,4,.....
Then I need to search next month if the same condition is true, and then next month until the end of the year(At least 4-6 month search)  (If the sum of the two positions from my starting matrix are found in the same lines of Apple, Blueberry and Apricot)
Another condition that I want to add is that after the value of the sum is found it needs to find at least one repetitive value within the last 4 numbers left where the condition was meet.
Then it should return as result  Apple no1+Apple no2(as text), the repetitive number as number, and the entire line within which matrix was found each month.
If there isn’t any True result I need to go further with the search of sum of  Apple no1 and Apple no3, then  sum of  Apple no1 and Apple no4 and so on, practically Apple no1 with each element of the Matrix. Until it finds the result that matches in the 4-6 month of research.

I am blocked, I'm not good in coding but I try my best to learn and understand I tried the same thing in SQL and gave me 9000 options each month,
Impossible
But from what I've seen i think in Java would it be possible